# How I can access the smb from linux?

Tags: windows, smb

I want to access the smb protocol in windows 8.1 from my linux pc 
and I know the username.

When I want to access by this command

```
smbclient //192.168.1.5/IPC$ -U kasp3r
```

it told me to put a password, but I don't put any password

I just hit Enter and the login is failed. Is there a default password? And what is it?

Comment: Try with this format.... `smbclient //<IPAddress>/<ShareName> <password> -U <username>` If you are connecting from one Windows PC to another without using a password, then that account on the machine you connect on the Windows machine you are logged on as likely has access to the other machine. On the Windows machine where this works from `cmd` just type in `echo %username%` and that will tell you the username to use. When you log into Windows with that account, that is the password otherwise it may not have one. Try just `smbclient //<IPAddress>/<ShareName> -U <username>` if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not connect to IPC, just connect to the PC or directly to the share.

You need to have a credentials (user and password) to connect your windows, if you do not have user on your windows you just can (i think) to leave them blank.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I know the username and the password I dont put a password on the windows ok I tried to login with blank password and username and I change them like one time tride to login with username with blank password and and vice versa and I have the windows pc and the linux pc

Comment: oh and give me the command to login to the PC using smbclient pleas